# USB-C and Apple Lightning inputs

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-analysis, digital-logic, pcb-design

I am wondering if there is a way for a device to receive power from both USB-C and lighting connectors. They would obviously be connected individually.

I was also wondering if it is possible to wire it so that when the Lightning cable is connected, a maximum of 5V will be delivered, and when the USB-C cable is connected, voltages of 1V and 3V can be delivered.

The device layout:
[image: device layout]

Comment: Is USB-C not a minimum 5V standard?  If you want to use 1-3V you should perhaps use a connector that won't be compatible with standard 5V sources.

Comment: You haven't explained your project well enough and you probably have an XY problem(google "XY problem" if you haven't heard of that).  Improve your question to get good responses.